# Eclipse Working set on basis of feature(s)

Tags: eclipse-rcp, working-set

IDE : Eclipse (Indigo) for RCP and RAP Developers version 3.7.0

It is possible to create working set in Eclipse to include plugins associated to a set of selected features?

This is to use the 5 features which internally links to 90+ plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, not that is not possible today. You will need to write a new working set implementation.